# Terminate Previous Download Request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, afnetworking

I am starting a `AFHTTPRequestOperation` to download some data from a server.

The action that triggers the download is text input from the user. I am working on making this dynamic, so if a user types: `a`, it will start fetching data for `a`. When a user adds another letter/changes the text, for example to `ab`, it will terminate the previous request and start a new one for `ab`. I am trying to have it dynamic.

Is there a way in `AFNetworking` to terminate a running request/operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `cancel` method on any operation...
If u r using `AFHTTPClient` there is a method `cancelAllHTTPOperationsWithMethod` to cancel an operation.
Or u can use `NSMutableSet` to track all the requests running in a view controller, and cancel one when u need.

Answer (score -1):

According to the AFNetworking reference there is no way to terminate the request.

Solution:
Just have a scheme to identify the various requests and ignore all but the last one.

Comment: `AFHTTPRequestOperation` does not have a `tag` or a similar property. How would I identify a request?